# Are "what lyric/text" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I imagine not, but Google won't help, so I would like to ask.

Ten+ years ago, in a hole-in-the-all heavy metal bar in Singapore (barely 2x3 metres), I had free beers all night translating lyrics (they loved the music, but had no clue about the words (!?)).

One song stick in mind, which progreesed (approximately):

> Du hast mich ...
>   Du hasst mich ...
>   Du hast mich     ... vergessen

As you can imagine, it was fun explaining that one - especially with much beer in the mix.

And I can no longer remenber which song it was, and "Google is not my friend".

Would it be on topic to ask here (as, for instance asking for a literary reference)?

BTW/sorry; it's late at night and ... gin ... so, please excuse/edit any (many?) speling errors (@Izzy , that's your job ;-)

Comment: Independent from what we may decide, [song identification](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-song/info) appears to be on-topic on [musicfans.se].

Comment: Thanks. I did not even know about that site. Being a music fan, I will become a regular. Of course, I will find more German speakers here than there ... Are literary reference questions on topic ("please identify this book or poem, from a quote")?

Comment: It's not [this one](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/5179/1442), isn't it?

Comment: Volltreffer!! Thank you so much, for the answer, and for the new community that I just joined. I misremembered [the lyrics](https://genius.com/Rammstein-du-hast-lyrics) a little - blame time and Tiger beer :-)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft music fans has subsequently decided to ban song identification questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, there is only a tag for `Grammatik-Identifikation`, no other `identification` tags.

However, there are similar questions open, for example:

- [Searching for a poem by Friedrich Hölderlin](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33905/searching-for-a-poem-by-friedrich-h%C3%B6lderlin) (2016)
- [Where are these verses from?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4293/where-are-these-verses-from) (2012)
- [Source of "Der Tod ist die letzte Feste dem Freien, deren Tor immer offen steht."](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/source-of-der-tod-ist-die-letzte-feste-dem-freien-deren-tor-immer-offen-steht) (2013)

So I guess, in general identification questions are on-topic.
Just make sure you provide as many details as possible.